# Convergent subsequence of $\sin n$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

It is well known (not to me -- ed.) that for every real number $\theta \in [0, 1]$  *there exists* a sequence $(k_i)$ such that $\lim\sin k_i = \theta,$ but there appear to be no explicit such (infinite) sequences, even for $\theta=0.$ Does anyone know of such?

Comment: This is a nice question, really horribly phrased (which is why some have voted to close) -- I will try to rewrite.

Comment: Presumably the $k_i$ are to be distinct positive integers.

Comment: Why is this not research level? Does any of the closers know the answer for any $\theta \neq 0?$

Comment: @IgorRivin: As you said, it is "horribly formulated". The OP asks for an explicit $(k_i)$ for each $\theta$ which is impossible: there are too many $\theta$'s and too few descriptions. For a given $\theta$ the question is about finding $k$ such that approximating $\arcsin(\theta)+2\pi k$ is close to an integer. An algorithm to find such a $k$ (for a good $\theta$) is obvious.

Comment: I do not understand the question or what? Why $\sin \frac1n$ does not satisfy you? It seems it is infinite and tends to zero. Or do you mean $k_n$ to be integer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As to the convergenge to zero: note that the convergents of the [continuous fraction for $\pi$](http://oeis.org/A001203) provide a rational approximation $|\pi - p_n/q_n|  < 1/q_nq_{n+1}$ so that $\sin p_n\to 0$.

The sequence of numerators      $0, 1, 3, 22, 333, 355,\dots$ is OEIS'  [A002485](http://oeis.org/A002485).

Comment: (stil there could be subsequences with a simpler expression than the $p_n$'s, which have no known closed formula)

Answer (score 8):

If you allow negative integers in your sequence, Pietro Majer's answer can be extended to the general case $\sin n \rightarrow \theta$. First, remark that, since $\sin$ is continuous it suffices to find a sequence of integer pairs $(u_n,v_n)$ such that $u_n+2\pi v_n \rightarrow \arcsin(\theta).$

Compute a continued fraction for $2\pi$ (instead of $\pi$ in the previous answer) with convergents $p_n/q_n$ and form the invertible matrix:
$$
M_n=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
q_n & p_n \\
q_{n+1} & p_{n+1}\end{array}\right).
$$

Let $V_n$ denotes the vector $(\lfloor q_n\arcsin(\theta)\rceil; \lfloor q_{n+1}\arcsin(\theta)\rceil).$ Consider the vector $W_n=M_n^{-1}V_n$, note that $W_n$ is an integer vector because $\det(M_n)=\pm 1$. If you rename the coordinates of $W_n$ by writing $W_n=(u_n;v_n)$ then $u_n/v_n \rightarrow \arcsin(\theta)$ and $\sin(u_n)\rightarrow \theta.$

*Heuristically*, you can probably expect the $u_n$ to contain an infinite subsequence of positive integers which would answer your initial question in the affirmative.

---

Example:

Take $\theta=1/10$ and $\alpha=\arcsin(\theta)\approx 0.1001674211615597963455231$. For $n=30$, we have:
$$
M_{30}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
842468587426513207 & 5293386250278608690 \\
68438367733593670 & 430010946591069243
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and $V_{30}=(6855294804380582;84387905812135908)$. We get $u_{30}=-1544426340857779936$ and $v_{30}=245803086388844114$.

And indeed:
$$
\sin(-1544426340857779936)\approx 0.099999999999999999558
$$

Answer (score 5):

Since $\pi$ is irrational, the sequence $n\bmod 2\pi$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$. Now use the fact that $\sin$ is continuous.

Comment: How does this give an *explicit* sequence?

Comment: Let $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$. Pick a decreasing sequence  of intervals  $I_k\subset [0,2\pi]$ collapsing on $\theta$. For each $k$ find $n_k$ such that $n_k\bmod 2\pi \in I_k$.  Then $\sin n_k\to \sin\theta$ as $k\to\infty$.